# CSS-Banner Adjustment: Scale

Tags: html, ios, css, wordpress, width

I'll be working with **full-screen banners**, just [like this one](http://accountabletest.com/contact-us/) or [this other one](http://accountabletest.com/) and for this purpose I'm using a plugin in a Wordpress site.

Now I have set their respective widths to **100%** (to avoid an x-axis scrolling and also to make the banners display fully on every screen size). Problem is that if you grab your browser screen to make it smaller or you open the web site on small screens (13 inch or iPads) the **images displayed on banners squish**.

`I need the image to be cutted off while resizing` and the only way I know for that is to **change the banner's div class** from `width: 100%` to `width:the amount of pixels I want` but in this way, obviously, if the screen from where you enter the site is smaller you'll get a x-axis scrolling and if it's bigger you'll have the banner cutted of when it reaches the amount of pixels previously set up in it's width.

**How can I get the images not to squish, but to get cutted off making it's div width display 100% on any browser?**

Banner's actual code:

```
.bannercustom { 
   position: relative;
   z-index: 11;
   left: -2px;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0px;
   float: left;
   height: 440px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to set the banner as a background-image to a div? Then you can set the background-scale to 100% and let the div resize as needed.

Comment: If I use the images I'm using in the banner plugin as backgrounds of my actual banner's div  I'll be loosing the banner's functionality ( to rotate randomly). @Dfross

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use: `width:auto;` ?

Should work.

Comment: Just tried so, but the effect is the same, the img inside the banner squishes.@user2973474